# Where to put methods that run when app starts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a few files I need to run when a Rails app first launches. They're configuration code for the CarrierWave and Shopify API gems. I currently have them in config/initializers, where they run correctly, but I've noticed they run during Rake tasks as well, which makes me wonder if this is the proper way of doing things. I've looked at the Rails Guides on initializers (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html), which are very in-depth and hard for me to follow. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: initializers are the first place which gets interpreted as the app starts, other place you can keep them is in your `application_controller.rb`

Comment: @amitkarsale Configuration should not be in a controller. Bad separation of concerns.

Comment: Sounds like we have some disagreement. Would it help if I included the code in question, or do you have enough to go on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the initializers running with the rake task sounds right to me. Imagine a rake task playing around with CarrierWave files.

Initializers are the good place for code that needs to run when the app boot.